# How to Convert/add String Array[] elements into List<String> [] Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I have three arrays of String

```
String array1 [] = {"A", "B", "C"};
String array2 [] = {"D", "E"};
String array3 [] = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};
```

I want to store all this arrays into List of String array.

```
List<String> allArrays[]
```

My output List allArrays[] should contain

```
allArrays[0]= [A,B,C]
allArrays[1]= [D,E]
allArrays[2]= [F,G,H,I]
```

I have tried below piece of code but getting null pointer exception

```
String array1 [] = {"A", "B", "C"};
String array2 [] = {"D", "E"};
String array3 [] = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};

List<String> allArrays[] =null;

allArrays[0].addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
//Null pointer exception here
allArrays[1].addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
allArrays[2].addAll(Arrays.asList(array3));

System.out.println(b[0]);
System.out.println(b[1]);
System.out.println(b[2]);
```

Comment: What do you think `List<String> allArrays[] =null;` does?

Comment: `List<String> allArrays[] =null;` How do you expect `allArrays`to be different from `null`?

Comment: Arrays and generic types don't work well. Rule of thumb is to prefer List over array so if you want to create something like `List<Foo>[]` then use `List<List<Foo>>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating and adding to the list correctly. Since you need an `array` of `List<String>`, you can do this:

```
String array1 [] = {"A", "B", "C"};
String array2 [] = {"D", "E"};
String array3 [] = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};
List<String>[] allArrays = new ArrayList[3]; 

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(list, array1);
allArrays[0] = list;
list = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(list, array2);
allArrays[1] = list;
list = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(list, array3);
allArrays[2] = list;
        
System.out.println(allArrays[0]);
System.out.println(allArrays[1]);
System.out.println(allArrays[2]);
```

Output:

```
[A, B, C]
[D, E]
[F, G, H, I]
```

A better way would be using `List<List<String>>`:

```
String array1 [] = {"A", "B", "C"};
String array2 [] = {"D", "E"};
String array3 [] = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};
List<List<String>> allArrays = new ArrayList<>(); 

allArrays.add(Arrays.asList(array1));
allArrays.add(Arrays.asList(array2));
allArrays.add(Arrays.asList(array3));
                
System.out.println(allArrays);
```

Output:

```
[[A, B, C], [D, E], [F, G, H, I]]
```

Comment: It would be neater to use `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array1));`, if you *really* need the inner lists to be array lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
String[] array1 = {"A", "B", "C"};
String[] array2 = {"D", "E"};
String[] array3 = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};

List<String>[] listArr = new ArrayList[3];
listArr[0] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array1));
listArr[1] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array2));
listArr[2] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array3));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(listArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of why this works when the OP's didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String array1 [] = {"A", "B", "C"};
String array2 [] = {"D", "E"};
String array3 [] = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};

List<String>[] allArrays = new List[] {
    Arrays.asList(array1),
    Arrays.asList(array2),
    Arrays.asList(array3)
};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allArrays));
```

output

```
[[A, B, C], [D, E], [F, G, H, I]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course you get a null Pointer Exception, because you need to creat a new List. If you set your List to null, you dont create a empty List, you just have a Object, which you can do nothing with.

```
    String array1 [] = {"A", "B", "C"};
    String array2 [] = {"D", "E"};
    String array3 [] = {"F", "G", "H", "I"};

    List<String[]> allArrays;
    
    allArrays = new LinkedList<>();


    allArrays.add(array1); 
    allArrays.add(array1); 
    allArrays.add(array1); 
    
    String[] array4 = allArrays.get(0);
    String[] array5 = allArrays.get(1);
    String[] array6 = allArrays.get(2);

    System.out.println(array4);
    System.out.println(array5);
    System.out.println(array6);
```

It should work if you do it with a LinkedList. By the way, are you using a IDE, when I put your code in Eclipse or any other IDE I get many Warnings, so the NullPointerException wasnt the only that doesnt work in your code.

Comment: an array of list is not a list of array

Comment: yeah I know, but I dont used it as often, as a LinkedList, but they work the same way, so I showed him my way

Comment: no. I mean `List<String>[]` is not the same as `List<String[]>` and OP asks for the first one

Comment: "I want to store all this arrays into List of String array" That is what he wanted and I thought I can also show him a other way, wich is very similar and also works good. I am sorry if that wasthe wrong way to answer that question.